# How can I return a specific object (index) from an arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, sentinel

I created a class called Student and assigned it 3 values (StudentNumber, Course, Mark); I then assigned a created student (s) to an arrayList called studentsCourses.

This way each student takes up an index in the array. But how do I get the students back OUT of the arrayList... if that makes sense? I have them stored, but I don't know how to recall the information so that I can see it.

```
public static void main (String[]args){
ArrayList<Student> studentsCourses= new ArrayList<Student>();
String studentNumber="~";
String course="~";
int mark=0;

Student pat;

Student s=null;

do{
  s=new Student();
  System.out.println("Please Enter Your Student ID (type quit to Quit):\n");
  studentNumber=keybrd.next();
  s.setStudentNumber(studentNumber);
  System.out.println("Please Enter Your Course ID:\n");
  course=keybrd.next();
  s.setCourse(course);
  System.out.println("Please Enter Your Mark:\n");
  mark=keybrd.nextInt();
  s.setMark(mark);
  s.printStates();
  studentsCourses.add(s);
}while(!studentNumber.equals("quit"));

System.out.println(studentsCourses.size());   
System.out.println(studentsCourses);
```

so if I wanted to assign the created student (pat) the state of index 1 how would I do that?

My one other issue (going along with this piece of code) is my sentinel. it does indeed quit when I type quit. but it finishes running through the "do" first. meaning I actually end up with a student who's number is "quit" course is whatever and mark is whatever.

How do I force it to break the do as soon as "quit" is typed?

Comment: What actually do you want to do?

Comment: I actually put off posting this for nearly an hour figuring I would find the simple solution and I didn't; now (5 minutes after posting it) I figured it out. And it was bloody simple 
pat=studentsCourses.get(index);

Comment: I still need to fix the sentinel part though if anyone can help me with that?

Comment: @Anubhab I want the program to ask the user their student number, a course name, and a mark for that course repeatedly until quit is typed. When quit is typed I want it to stop prompting and move to the next part of the code.

Comment: Any reason my question was voted down?

Comment: i guess someone downvoted because your question was really easy. If you could google it more or study some core java you could answer it yourself.

Comment: but isn't that the point of this site.. everything I google pretty much brings me to this site; and I couldn't find the answer ON this site; so I asked the question. I can't imagine this is the simplest answer ever asked on here..

Comment: Haha..Don't get offended man..chill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But how do I get the students back OUT of the arrayList... if that makes sense? I have them stored, but I don't know how to recall the information so that I can see it."

To get the data from arraylist:

```
for (Student student : studentsCourses) {
        System.out.println(student.getStudentNumber());
        System.out.println(student.getCourse());
        System.out.println(student.getMarkr());
    }
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentsCourses.size(); i++) {
        Student student = studentsCourses.get(i);
        System.out.println(student.getStudentNumber());
        System.out.println(student.getCourse());
        System.out.println(student.getMarkr());
    }
```

to solve other issue, you can try:

```
      do{
          s=new Student();
          System.out.println("Please Enter Your Student ID (type quit to Quit):\n");
          studentNumber=keybrd.next();
          if(studentNumber.equals("quit"))
              break;
          s.setStudentNumber(studentNumber);
          System.out.println("Please Enter Your Course ID:\n");
          course=keybrd.next();
          s.setCourse(course);
          System.out.println("Please Enter Your Mark:\n");
          mark=keybrd.nextInt();
          s.setMark(mark);
          s.printStates();
          studentsCourses.add(s);
        }while(true);
```

Comment: you sir, are a brilliant man :) thank you very much inserting the if statement worked perfectly. I didn't realize you could put "}while(true)" 
What exactly is that saying? While what is true?

Comment: @Anubhab very; isn't it obvious :)

Comment: @vishal_aim: the way you have mentioned to visit a list is fine but it brings down the performance when list has 1000 entries or so. In that case i guess using a hashmap helps if you have any unique identifier in the records like : id,no. etc..

Comment: @Anubhab it depends, if at the end we just have to show all results, list is better (sequential access), if we need to look up any element (student by unique id) then of course hashmap is much better

Comment: @Vishal_aim: yes that is correct. If you want a report then this is best. :)

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList is not an array... It's a List which uses arrays as its backing store.

The retrieval method from list is `list.get(index)`

Alternately, you can use some syntactic sugar to just loop over them

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
// add students
for (Student student : students) {
  // do something with student
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29)method to retrieve an element.

Use [`add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)method to insert an element at an index.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.out.println("Please Enter Your Student ID (type quit to Quit):\n");
        studentNumber=keybrd.next();

        while (!studentNumber.equals("quit")){
            s=new Student();

            s.setStudentNumber(studentNumber);
            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Course ID:\n");
            course=keybrd.next();
            s.setCourse(course);
            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Mark:\n");
            mark=keybrd.nextInt();
            s.setMark(mark);
            s.printStates();
            studentsCourses.add(s);

            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Student ID (type quit to Quit):\n");
            studentNumber=keybrd.next();
        }
```

Comment: This being a fencepost loop, correct? I did try it without the do statement but not as a fencepost loop... I'll give it a shot; thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to know:-

Firstly, you're using a `do-while` loop, which is an **exit check** loop, hence it will execute once atleast, before terminating. If you want to avoid it, try using a `while` loop.

Next, to retrieve all elements from the list, you can either use the `list.get(index)` or the `for` loop traversal  as below:-

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
for (Student student : students) {
    // Do something with the student object.
}
```

**Update:-**

The `for` you've seen above, is actually **Foreach** loop. This is what it means

```
for each item in collection:
  do something to item
```

Hence, the loop means,

> for each **item(student)** in **collection(students)**
>   do something to **item(student)**

Now coming back to looping part. Forget everything, and just use a `break;`.

After this piece of code `studentNumber=keybrd.next();`, do a check and **break** the loop.

```
if(studentNumber.equals("quit")){
    break;
}
```

Simple solution.

Comment: Am I missing something with the "while" loop? Because 3 people have suggested a while loop now but that was what I started with... it was giving me the same issue and the do..while was an attempted solution.

Also if you don't mind could you expand on the for (Student student : students){ 
I don't really understand what it's doing? The first "Student" is the class; the second would be the name? and after the colon?

Comment: @OscarWilde - Check my update, just to know what happens in that `Foreach`.

Comment: thanks for laying it out so simply! Makes perfect sense; And I did end up going with the if..break option ; Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `toString()` method to your Students class :

```
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
      return "\tStudentNumber: " + studentNumber
                + "\tCourse: " + course 
                + "\tMarks: " + marks;

  }
```

And then you can say :

```
   System.out.println(studentsCourses);
```

As far as this is concerned :

```
   How do I force it to break the do as soon as "quit" is typed?
```

This behaviour is because you are using `do..while()` ! Try using `while` instead.

Comment: I did actually use while originally and it was giving me the same issue; the do..while was my attempt at a solution :) thank you though!

and for the moment just using "list.get(index)" seems to be enough but I will keep toString in mind

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a hashmap with key as Student number and Object to that key as Student Object. In this way you could avoid duplication as well.

**For the sentinel**

```
         // 1. Create a Scanner using the InputStream available.
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        String input=null;
do{
        // 2. Don't forget to prompt the user
        System.out.print( "Type some data for the program: " );

        // 3. Use the Scanner to read a line of text from the user.
         input = scanner.nextLine();

        // 4. Now, you can do anything with the input string that you need to.
        // Like, output it to the user.
        System.out.println( "input = " + input );
}while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
```